# Disable python warnings only for specific module via commandline

Tags: python

When starting my Python script I'm getting this warning:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cffi/model.py:526: UserWarning: 'point_conversion_form_t' has no values explicitly defined; next version will refuse to guess which integer type it is meant to be (unsigned/signed, int/long)
  % self._get_c_name())
```

I know I can ignore this warning like this:

```
PYTHONWARNINGS="ignore::UserWarning" python $MYSCRIPT
```

But this will also ignore UserWarnings from all other modules that I would still like to see.
Is it possible to specify the ignore in a more fine-grained way, like passing the module name for which warnings should be suppressed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will ignore UserWarnings only for module `cffi.model` via command line:

```
PYTHONWARNINGS="ignore::UserWarning:cffi.model" python $MYSCRIPT
```

Answer (score -2):

You can do this in your code, see the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#temporarily-suppressing-warnings)

```
import warnings

def fxn():
    warnings.warn("deprecated", DeprecationWarning)

with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
    fxn()
```